# Pointer allowing to store more than allocated size

Tags: c

Size of an int is 4 bytes and I am allocating only 1 byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int *a = (int *) malloc(1);

    // But I am still able to store int.
    *a = 42;
    printf("%d\n", *a);

    // It also allowed me to store char in an int pointer.
    *a = 'H';
    printf("%c\n", *a);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why undefined behavior sometimes does what you want?

Comment: @Tom Krazes yes

Comment: There are probably a very large number of duplicates of this question on the site and I'm not sure how best to resolve that. Is there a canonical best one we should keep?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: I chose a fairly old, fairly highly voted one that covered a nearly identical case (allocate one byte, store more). Seemed more than close enough.

Comment: Side-note: On "It also allowed me to store char in an int pointer"; one, that would be legal if you'd allocated enough memory for it in any event (it would just expand it to `int` size), but two, `'H'` is actually an `int` in C (character literals are of type `int` in C, yes it's odd, and no, it's not the same in C++, where character literals are in fact of type `char`).

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
int* a = (int*) malloc(1);
*a = 42;
```

Is **undefined behavior**.  It might seem to work for now, but maybe not later. But in practice, you've corrupted the heap.  All bets are off on what your program's behavior might be - especially as you add more code and do more malloc/free calls later.

This statement:

```
*a='H';
```

Is also unsafe.  It's equivalent to this:

```
*a = (int)'H';
```

Which is equivalent to this (assuming ascii):

```
*a = 72;
```

You're probably getting lucky because malloc likely allocates memory on word aligned boundaries. But don't design your program to rely on that.

Comment: s/lucky/unlucky/ because it's hiding the bug